# How to prevent the javascript Alert to change the active window

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alert

I use a java script file for my calculations in an asp.net page  . If user write wrong values in some of the textboxes I show a message to them using a simple ALert :

```
 if (parseFloat(ctrltotal.value) < totalEX) {
            alert(" Error message ");
            return false;
        }
```

My problem is that when the alert message comes up , active windows switches from the current active window which is my browser to another windows (any other open window on the system). is there any why to prevent this ?

Thank you.

Comment: It is a simple alert , it in the  question now. Thanks

Comment: Did you test `window.focus();` after alert ?

Comment: Does not work, there is no problem after closing the alert, my problem is that alert opens on the other windows and after clicking on OK btn comes back to the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can save the active element before you click the button and re-focus that element after alert box dissappears.

Example:

```
<div>
    <div> Input A: <input type="text" /> </div>
    <div> Input B: <input type="text" /> </div>
    <div> Input C: <input type="text" /> </div>
    <div> Input D: <input type="text" /> </div>
    <div> Input E: <input type="text" /> </div>
    <div> Input F: <input type="text" /> </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn">Click</button>
```

You can use `on mouse down` event of the button and get the active document element (click event is too late since clicked button would "steal" the active element) and re-focus it after the alert box.

```
var focused = null;

document.getElementById('btn').onmousedown = function(){
    focused = document.activeElement;
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
    alert('Hello');
    if (focused != null) focused.focus();
}
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8bvyf16q/